# Setting android core - system aosp log debug variables at runtime

Tags: android, android-source

While hacking the aosp code, and running a custom Android image, I regularly bump into debug variables within the core/system code that I'd love to toggle to true.

Let's take for example the DEBUG_ALL boolean in the aosp sources frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerDebugConfig.java

I already know how to recompile the framework module so I could set it to true, recompile and adb install. But I'm wondering if there's a way to toggle this variable at runtime, from adb shell for instance?